# the places / everywhere / wherever - all possible here?

Tags: relative-pronouns

I'm perfectly comfortable saying this:

> 1. My house is close to the places that I go to most often to meet my friends.

But, how about these ones? Are these sentences natural?

> 2. My house is close to wherever I go to meet my friends.
> 3. My house is close to everywhere I go to meet my friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The '2' sounds OK.  The '3' - not so much.  I think the reason is the "everywhere" maxim.  No place can be "close to everywhere".  Note that there is a significant difference between "wherever" and "everywhere".